# Эффект воды GLSL С++ OpenGL

Tags: c++, glsl, opengl-3.3

[Программа](https://disk.yandex.ru/d/EUSrODZrnzMH_A)

Если кто-то решит помочь кодом

- Обновить шейдер - F6

Управление

- ESC Скрыть/Показать интерфейс
- Стрелки - движение
- Мышь - вращение
- f5 Обновить шейдеры и простые текстуры и меш,  шейдеры .
- f6 Перезагрузить только шейдеры
- Загрузить нормальные текстуры кнопка в окне Height S.. Load big...

---

Пытаюсь сделать воду без кучи непонятных мне формул.
Делаю все через шейдеры, Прошу помощи понятной  идеей на русском. Английский не знаю.

Сейчас суть такова, Я в вершинном шейдере в зависимости от позиции вершины и времени применил эффект синуса и косинуса наварист, для имитации псевдо преломления.

В вершинном крашу все что ниже линии океана в цвет океана  с коэффициентом поверх картинки конечно. Эффект не очень ели честно. Возможно есть что-то лучше синуса?

У меня меша океана нет вообще если честно, только иллюзия, так можно делать?

Возможно что-то простое как синус и косинус лучше имитирует волны?

---

Над водой

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

И под водой

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вершинный

```
    #version 330 core
    layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
    layout (location = 1) in vec3 aNormal;
    layout (location = 2) in vec2 aTexCoords;
    
    layout (location = 3) in vec3 aTangent;
    layout (location = 4) in vec3 aBitangent;  
    
    out vec3 fragPos;
    out vec3 Normal;
    out vec2 TexCoords;
    out mat3 TBN;
    
    uniform mat4 model;
    uniform mat4 view;
    uniform mat4 projection;
    
    uniform float Time;
    
    uniform float HeightOcean;
    uniform float IntrvalOcean;
    uniform bool EnableOcean;
    uniform vec3 ColorOcean;
    //пОЗИЦИЯ КАМЕРЫ
    uniform vec3 CamPos;
    
    
    void main()
    {
    
        //Вершина для модефикаций
        vec3 NaPos = aPos ;
        
        
        //Даные для отправки в фрагментный
        fragPos = vec3(model * vec4(NaPos, 1.0));
        Normal = mat3(transpose(inverse(model))) * aNormal;  
        TexCoords = aTexCoords;
        
        vec3 T = normalize(vec3(model * vec4(aTangent,   0.0)));
        vec3 B = normalize(vec3(model * vec4(aBitangent, 0.0)));
        vec3 N = normalize(vec3(model * vec4(aNormal,    0.0)));
        TBN = mat3(T, B, N);;    
          
        if(EnableOcean)
        {
            //float NIntrvalOcean = IntrvalOcean;
            
            
            
            float NIntrvalOcean = (1 - (NaPos.y / HeightOcean ))*IntrvalOcean;
            
            if(NaPos.y < HeightOcean-0.1)
            {
                float MOD = sin(Time*2+NaPos.x)*NIntrvalOcean + cos(Time*1+NaPos.z)*NIntrvalOcean;
            NaPos.y = NaPos.y;
        

        float DistVN = HeightOcean - NaPos.y;
        
        //Если персонаж ниже уровня моря
        if(CamPos.y>HeightOcean)
        NaPos.y = (NaPos.y + DistVN / 3) + MOD; //Немного убераем глубину и делаем преломления
        else
        NaPos.y = NaPos.y + MOD/5; //Камера под водой, ефект преломления меньше ПСЕВДО ПРЕЛОМЛЕНИЕ ДАЖЕ ПАРОДИЯ НА ЕТО
        }
        else
        {
            if(CamPos.y<=HeightOcean) //Преломления уже на поверхности ясли камера под водой
            {
                float MOD = sin(Time*2+NaPos.x)*NIntrvalOcean + cos(Time*1+NaPos.z)*NIntrvalOcean;
                NaPos.y  = NaPos.y  +MOD;
            }
        }
    }
        
        
    //Применить трашсформации и отправить по конвееру
    gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(NaPos, 1.0);
}
```

Фрагментный

```
#version 330 core
out vec4 FragColor;


//Сколько каких источников
#define NR_POINT_LIGHTS 50
#define NR_SPOT_LIGHTS 10
#define NR_DIR_LIGHTS 2


//Матеріал 
struct Material {
    sampler2D diffuse;
    sampler2D specular;
    sampler2D normalMap;
    float shininess;
}; 

struct DirLight {
    bool enable;
    vec3 direction;
    vec3 ambient;
    vec3 diffuse;
    vec3 specular;
};

struct PointLight {
    bool enable;
    vec3 position;
    
    float constant;
    float linear;
    float quadratic;
    
    vec3 ambient;
    vec3 diffuse;
    vec3 specular;
};

struct SpotLight {
    bool enable;
    vec3 position;
    vec3 direction;
    float cutOff;
    float outerCutOff;
  
    float constant;
    float linear;
    float quadratic;
  
    vec3 ambient;
    vec3 diffuse;
    vec3 specular;       
};

struct FogST
{
    bool enable;
    vec3 fogColor;
    float heightMax;
    float heightMin; 
    float startFog;
    float endFog;
};

vec3 FonLight;

in vec3 fragPos;
in vec3 Normal;
in vec2 TexCoords;
in mat3 TBN;

//Модефикатор текстур
vec2 texCoords;

//Позиция камеры
uniform vec3 CamPos;

uniform DirLight dirLight[NR_DIR_LIGHTS];
uniform PointLight pointLights[NR_POINT_LIGHTS];
uniform SpotLight spotLight[NR_SPOT_LIGHTS];
uniform vec3 fonLight  = vec3(0.1,0.1,0.1);
uniform Material material;
//Использовать текстуру нормалей ?
uniform bool NormalMapEnable = true;

//Смещение текстур
uniform vec2 ModTextCords = vec2(0,0);

//Туман
uniform FogST Fog;

//Свет
uniform bool lightEnable = true;

// function prototypes
vec3 CalcDirLight(DirLight light, vec3 normal, vec3 viewDir);
vec3 CalcPointLight(PointLight light, vec3 normal, vec3 fragPos, vec3 viewDir);
vec3 CalcSpotLight(SpotLight light, vec3 normal, vec3 fragPos, vec3 viewDir);

//Experemental
uniform float HeightOcean;
uniform float IntrvalOcean;
uniform bool EnableOcean;
uniform vec3 ColorOcean;

void main()
{    
vec3 result; //Результат цвета 

vec3 viewPos = CamPos;
//vec3 viewPos = ViewPos;
vec3 FragPos = fragPos;

//Камера под водой?
bool OceanCam = viewPos.y<= HeightOcean;

//Растояние между точкой и камирой
float DisF = distance(viewPos,FragPos);
//Коефициент тумана
  if(Fog.enable)
  {

        if(DisF > Fog.startFog) //Толька после начала
        {
            DisF = (DisF-Fog.startFog) /(Fog.endFog-Fog.startFog);
        }
        else
        if(DisF > Fog.endFog) //если конец тумана 
        {
            DisF = 1; //100%
        }
        else //Тут нет тумана
        {
            DisF = 0;
        }
        
        //Высота тумана
        //float Heigh = distance(viewPos.y,FragPos.y);
        //Потом удалить зависимость от камеры возможно
        
        float Max = Fog.heightMax + viewPos.y;
        float Min = Fog.heightMin + viewPos.y;
        float Point = FragPos.y;
        
         if(Point<HeightOcean) //На воде уменньшыть туман
             DisF = DisF*0.7;
        
        if(Point > Max) DisF = 0;
        else
        if(DisF>1)
            DisF = 1; //Нормализация
        //if(Point < Min) DisF = 0;
        float MixC = 1;
        
        //Здвиг в 0
        float Nmax = Max - Min;
        float Npoint = Point - Min;
        
        
        MixC = 1-(Npoint / Nmax) ;//  (Point-Min)-((Max - Min ) / Max);
        
        DisF = DisF*MixC;
        
        //if(FragPos.y<Fog.heightMax && FragPos.y>Fog.heightMin)
        // DisF = DisF * (1/(Fog.heightMax-Fog.heightMin));
        
        
        //(DisF-Fog.startFog) /(Fog.endFog-Fog.startFog);
        
        

        if(DisF>=1) { //Не делать расчеты света бесполезно там уже 100 тумана
           FragColor = vec4(Fog.fogColor, 1.0);
           return;
        }
  }
  
//Здвиг
texCoords = TexCoords + ModTextCords;

if(lightEnable)
{

    vec3 viewDir = normalize(viewPos - FragPos);
    vec3 norm;
    if(NormalMapEnable)
    {
    // преобразование из диапазона [-1,1] в диапазон [0,1]  
    vec3 normRGB = texture(material.normalMap, texCoords).rgb * 2 -1;
    norm =  normalize(TBN * normRGB); 
    }
    else
    {
        norm = Normal;
    }


        //фон
        result = vec3(texture(material.diffuse, texCoords)) * fonLight;

        // phase 1: direct 
        for(int i = 0; i < NR_DIR_LIGHTS; i++)
        if(dirLight[i].enable)
        result += CalcDirLight(dirLight[i], norm, viewDir);
        

        // phase 2: point lights
        for(int i = 0; i < NR_POINT_LIGHTS; i++)
        if(pointLights[i].enable)
            result += CalcPointLight(pointLights[i], norm, FragPos, viewDir); 
        // phase 3: spot light
        for(int i = 0; i < NR_SPOT_LIGHTS; i++)
        if(spotLight[i].enable)
        result += CalcSpotLight(spotLight[i], norm, FragPos, viewDir);    
      
}
else //Отключен свет значит только текстура
{
    result = vec3(texture(material.diffuse, texCoords));
}


{
    float Point = FragPos.y;
    
    bool PointOcean = Point<HeightOcean; //Точка под водой
    
    if(OceanCam && !PointOcean) //Камера под водой
    {
        result = mix(result,ColorOcean,  0.7 );
    }
        
    if(PointOcean)
    {
        
        //float DisF = distance(viewPos,FragPos);
        float Cof =  1-Point/HeightOcean+0.4; //Закрасить дно
        if(Cof>1) Cof = 1;
        
        float DisVF = distance(viewPos,FragPos); //Растояние между камерой и точкой
         Cof = Cof * (DisVF/50);
         if(Cof>1)Cof = 1;
        
        result = mix(result, ColorOcean , Cof  );
    }
}

//if(OceanCam)
//result = mix(result,ColorOcean,  0.5 );

  
  //if(distance(viewPos,FragPos)>50)
      
  if(Fog.enable) //Применить туман
  {
    result = mix(result,Fog.fogColor,  DisF  ); //
    }  
  
  
    //Альфа с цветной текстуры
   FragColor = vec4(result, texture(material.diffuse, texCoords)[3]);

    
    //FragColor = texture(material.diffuse, texCoords);
}

// 00000 calculates the color when using a directional light.
vec3 CalcDirLight(DirLight light, vec3 normal, vec3 viewDir)
{
   vec3 lightDir = normalize(-light.direction);
   

   float diff = 1;
  
    diff   = max(dot(normal, lightDir), 0.0);
    //diff   = max(dot(Normal, lightDir), 0.0);
   
   
    vec3 reflectDir = reflect(-lightDir, normal);  
    float spec = pow(max(dot(viewDir, reflectDir), 0.0), material.shininess);
    vec3 specular = light.specular * spec * texture(material.specular, texCoords).rgb;  
    

    vec3 diffuse = light.diffuse * vec3(texture(material.diffuse, texCoords)) * diff;
    //vec3 specular = light.specular  * vec3(texture(material.specular, texCoords));
    return diffuse + specular + light.ambient * vec3(texture(material.diffuse, texCoords))  ;
}

// calculates the color when using a point light.
vec3 CalcPointLight(PointLight light, vec3 normal, vec3 fragPos, vec3 viewDir)
{
    vec3 lightDir = normalize(light.position - fragPos);
    // diffuse shading
    float diff = max(dot(normal, lightDir), 0.0);
    // specular shading
    vec3 reflectDir = reflect(-lightDir, normal);
    float spec = pow(max(dot(viewDir, reflectDir), 0.0), material.shininess);
    // attenuation
    float distance = length(light.position - fragPos);
    float attenuation = 1.0 / (light.constant + light.linear * distance + light.quadratic * (distance * distance));    
    // combine results
  //  vec3 ambient = light.ambient * vec3(texture(material.diffuse, texCoords));
    vec3 diffuse = light.diffuse * diff * vec3(texture(material.diffuse, texCoords));
    vec3 specular = light.specular * spec * vec3(texture(material.specular, texCoords));
    
    diffuse *= attenuation;
    specular *= attenuation;
    return (diffuse + specular);
}

// calculates the color when using a spot light.
vec3 CalcSpotLight(SpotLight light, vec3 normal, vec3 fragPos, vec3 viewDir)
{
    vec3 lightDir = normalize(light.position - fragPos);
    // diffuse shading
    float diff = max(dot(normal, lightDir), 0.0);
    // specular shading
    vec3 reflectDir = reflect(-lightDir, normal);
    float spec = pow(max(dot(viewDir, reflectDir), 0.0), material.shininess);
    // attenuation
    float distance = length(light.position - fragPos);
    float attenuation = 1.0 / (light.constant + light.linear * distance + light.quadratic * (distance * distance));    
    // spotlight intensity
    float theta = dot(lightDir, normalize(-light.direction)); 
    float epsilon = light.cutOff - light.outerCutOff;
    float intensity = clamp((theta - light.outerCutOff) / epsilon, 0.0, 1.0);
    // combine results
    vec3 ambient = light.ambient * vec3(texture(material.diffuse, texCoords));
    vec3 diffuse = light.diffuse * diff * vec3(texture(material.diffuse, texCoords));
    vec3 specular = light.specular * spec * vec3(texture(material.specular, texCoords));
    
    ambient *= attenuation * intensity;
    diffuse *= attenuation * intensity;
    specular *= attenuation * intensity;
    return (ambient + diffuse + specular);
}
```

Comment: Очень сильно не хватает отражений и бликов на поверхности.

Comment: Да, есть такое так как поверхности вообще нет,  вот я и думаю создать меш  воды, что сильно урежет фпс, Иле просто подумать как наложить блики на дно чтобы была иллюзия что есть меш воды, фпс не пострадает, но реально нужно подумать как это рассчитать.

Comment: Решил блики сделать в геометрическом шейдере, но я подключил буквально пустой шейдер принял отправил далее, фпс просело вдвое с какого такой эффект? когда не использовал свой фпс 100, привязал 50 и меньше.?