# Геометрический шейдер Убивает FPS в чистом виде GLSL

Tags: c++, glsl, opengl-3.3

Ранее задавал [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1315481/%D0%AD%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8B-glsl-%D0%A1-opengl) о эффекте воды, один из пользователей сказал что не хватает бликов. Так как отдельного меша воды у меня нет да и напряжённо делать, да м шейдеры это более универсально для меня, решил сделать это в геометрическом шейдере, так как он может создавать дополнительные треугольники, то что нужно передаем из программы что сейчас рисуем ландшафт и если одна с точек треугольника ниже 0 создаем в координатах 0 треугольник для бликов со своей периодичностью.

Ранее геометрический даже не подключал. Вот что было с фпс.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Но вот подключил геометрический шейдер, первый ужас, нужно праветь вершинный шейдер, так как с вершинного в фрагментный шейдер транзитом данные не проходят те что OUT. Вот картина.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вот  можно сказать пустой геометрический шейдер

```
#version 330 core
layout (triangles) in;
layout (triangle_strip, max_vertices = 3) out;


void main() {  
for(int i = 0;i<3;i++)
{   
    gl_Position = gl_in[i].gl_Position; 
    EmitVertex();
}

    EndPrimitive();
}
```

Мало того что рисует не то, но и ФПС Упал.

Думаю ладно сделаю переотправку, правлю Вершынниынный шейдер.
Делаю транзит через геометричиский в фрагментный. И тут фпс вообще в раз 5 упало.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все шейдеры
Вершынный

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 aNormal;
layout (location = 2) in vec2 aTexCoords;

layout (location = 3) in vec3 aTangent;
layout (location = 4) in vec3 aBitangent;  




out vec3 fragPosG; 
out vec3 NormalG;
out vec2 TexCoordsG;
out mat3 TBNG;

uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;

uniform float Time;

uniform float HeightOcean;
uniform float IntrvalOcean;
uniform bool EnableOcean;
uniform vec3 ColorOcean;

uniform vec3 CamPos;

uniform bool OceanMesh = false; //Меш океана


void main()
{

    vec3 NaPos = aPos ;
    
    

    fragPosG = vec3(model * vec4(NaPos, 1.0));
    NormalG = mat3(transpose(inverse(model))) * aNormal;  
     
    
     
    TexCoordsG = aTexCoords;
    
      vec3 T = normalize(vec3(model * vec4(aTangent,   0.0)));
      vec3 B = normalize(vec3(model * vec4(aBitangent, 0.0)));
      vec3 N = normalize(vec3(model * vec4(aNormal,    0.0)));
      TBNG = mat3(T, B, N);;    

      
    float MOD;
float NIntrvalOcean;

if(OceanMesh)
        {
         NaPos.y = HeightOcean-0.1;
        }       
      
    if(EnableOcean)
    {
        //float NIntrvalOcean = IntrvalOcean;
        
        
        
        NIntrvalOcean = (1 - (NaPos.y / HeightOcean ))*IntrvalOcean;
        
        if(fragPosG.y < HeightOcean-0.1)
        {
            float MOD = sin(Time*2+NaPos.x)*NIntrvalOcean + cos(Time*1+NaPos.z)*NIntrvalOcean;
        NaPos.y = NaPos.y;
        
        float DistVN = HeightOcean - NaPos.y;
        
        //Если персонаж ниже уровня моря
        if(CamPos.y>HeightOcean)
        NaPos.y = (NaPos.y + DistVN / 3) + MOD; //Немного убераем глубину и делаем преломления
        else
        NaPos.y = NaPos.y + MOD/5; //Камера под водой, ефект преломления меньше ПСЕВДО ПРЕЛОМЛЕНИЕ ДАЖЕ ПАРОДИЯ НА ЕТО
        }
        else
        {
            if(CamPos.y<=HeightOcean)
            {
                MOD = sin(Time*2+NaPos.x)*NIntrvalOcean + cos(Time*1+NaPos.z)*NIntrvalOcean;
                NaPos.y  = NaPos.y  +MOD;
            }
        }
    }
        
        
        if(OceanMesh)
        {
        // NIntrvalOcean = 0.3;
        // MOD = sin(Time*2+NaPos.x)*NIntrvalOcean + cos(Time*1+NaPos.z)*NIntrvalOcean;
         NaPos.y += MOD;
         //NormalG.x += MOD;
        }     
        
    gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(NaPos, 1.0);



}
```

Геометричиский с транзитом нужных данных

```
 #version 330 core
layout (triangles) in;
layout (triangle_strip, max_vertices = 3) out;



//Переотправка

in vec3 fragPosG[];
in vec3 NormalG[];
in vec2 TexCoordsG[];
in mat3 TBNG[];


out vec3 fragPos; 
out vec3 Normal;
out vec2 TexCoords;
out mat3 TBN;


void main() {  

for(int i = 0;i<3;i++)
{
    //Переотправка для каждой точки
    fragPos = fragPosG[i];
    Normal = NormalG[i];
    TexCoords = TexCoordsG[i];
    TBN = TBNG[i];
    
    gl_Position = gl_in[i].gl_Position; 
    EmitVertex();
}

    EndPrimitive();
}
```

//И самый большой фрагментный

```
#version 330 core
out vec4 FragColor;


#define NR_POINT_LIGHTS 50
#define NR_SPOT_LIGHTS 10
#define NR_DIR_LIGHTS 2


//
struct Material {
    sampler2D diffuse;
    sampler2D specular;
    sampler2D normalMap;
    float shininess;
}; 

struct DirLight {
    bool enable;
    vec3 direction;
    vec3 ambient;
    vec3 diffuse;
    vec3 specular;
};

struct PointLight {
    bool enable;
    vec3 position;
    
    float constant;
    float linear;
    float quadratic;
    
    vec3 ambient;
    vec3 diffuse;
    vec3 specular;
};

struct SpotLight {
    bool enable;
    vec3 position;
    vec3 direction;
    float cutOff;
    float outerCutOff;
  
    float constant;
    float linear;
    float quadratic;
  
    vec3 ambient;
    vec3 diffuse;
    vec3 specular;       
};


struct FogST
{
    bool enable;
    
    vec3 fogColor;
    
    float heightMax;
    
    float heightMin; 
    

    float startFog;
    
    float endFog;
};



    vec3 FonLight;



in vec3 fragPos;
in vec3 Normal;
in vec2 TexCoords;
in mat3 TBN;



vec2 texCoords;


uniform vec3 CamPos;

uniform DirLight dirLight[NR_DIR_LIGHTS];
uniform PointLight pointLights[NR_POINT_LIGHTS];
uniform SpotLight spotLight[NR_SPOT_LIGHTS];
uniform vec3 fonLight  = vec3(0.1,0.1,0.1);
uniform Material material;

uniform bool NormalMapEnable = true;


uniform vec2 ModTextCords = vec2(0,0);






uniform FogST Fog;


uniform bool lightEnable = true;
 


// function prototypes
vec3 CalcDirLight(DirLight light, vec3 normal, vec3 viewDir);
vec3 CalcPointLight(PointLight light, vec3 normal, vec3 fragPos, vec3 viewDir);
vec3 CalcSpotLight(SpotLight light, vec3 normal, vec3 fragPos, vec3 viewDir);

//Experemental
uniform float HeightOcean;
uniform float IntrvalOcean;
uniform bool EnableOcean;
uniform vec3 ColorOcean;
uniform bool OceanMesh = false; //Меш океана


void main()
{    
vec3 result; 



     

vec3 viewPos = CamPos;
//vec3 viewPos = ViewPos;
vec3 FragPos = fragPos;



bool OceanCam = viewPos.y<= HeightOcean;






float DisF = distance(viewPos,FragPos);

  if(Fog.enable)
  {

        if(DisF > Fog.startFog) 
        {
            DisF = (DisF-Fog.startFog) /(Fog.endFog-Fog.startFog);
        }
        else
        if(DisF > Fog.endFog) 
        {
            DisF = 1; 
        }
        else 
        {
            DisF = 0;
        }
        
        
        //float Heigh = distance(viewPos.y,FragPos.y);
        
        
        float Max = Fog.heightMax + viewPos.y;
        float Min = Fog.heightMin + viewPos.y;
        float Point = FragPos.y;
        
        
        
        
         if(Point<HeightOcean) 
             DisF = DisF*0.7;
        
        
        
        if(Point > Max) DisF = 0;
        else
        if(DisF>1)
            DisF = 1; 
        //if(Point < Min) DisF = 0;
        float MixC = 1;
        
        
        float Nmax = Max - Min;
        float Npoint = Point - Min;
        
        
        MixC = 1-(Npoint / Nmax) ;//  (Point-Min)-((Max - Min ) / Max);
        
        DisF = DisF*MixC;
        
        //if(FragPos.y<Fog.heightMax && FragPos.y>Fog.heightMin)
        // DisF = DisF * (1/(Fog.heightMax-Fog.heightMin));
        
        
        //(DisF-Fog.startFog) /(Fog.endFog-Fog.startFog);
        
        

        if(DisF>=1) { 
           FragColor = vec4(Fog.fogColor, 1.0);
           return;
        }
  }
  
 



texCoords = TexCoords + ModTextCords;

if(lightEnable)
{

    vec3 viewDir = normalize(viewPos - FragPos);
    vec3 norm;
    if(NormalMapEnable)
    {
    
    vec3 normRGB = texture(material.normalMap, texCoords).rgb * 2 -1;
    norm =  normalize(TBN * normRGB); 
    }
    else
    {
        norm = Normal;
    }


        
        result = vec3(texture(material.diffuse, texCoords)) * fonLight;

    

        
        // phase 1: direct 
        for(int i = 0; i < NR_DIR_LIGHTS; i++)
        if(dirLight[i].enable)
        result += CalcDirLight(dirLight[i], norm, viewDir);
        

        
        
        // phase 2: point lights
        for(int i = 0; i < NR_POINT_LIGHTS; i++)
        if(pointLights[i].enable)
            result += CalcPointLight(pointLights[i], norm, FragPos, viewDir); 


        // phase 3: spot light
        for(int i = 0; i < NR_SPOT_LIGHTS; i++)
        if(spotLight[i].enable)
        result += CalcSpotLight(spotLight[i], norm, FragPos, viewDir);    
      
}
else 
{
    result = vec3(texture(material.diffuse, texCoords));
}





{
    float Point = FragPos.y;
    
    
    
    
    bool PointOcean = Point<HeightOcean; 
    
    
    
    if(OceanCam && !PointOcean) 
    {
        result = mix(result,ColorOcean,  0.7 );
    }
        
    
    
    
    if(PointOcean)
    {
        
        //float DisF = distance(viewPos,FragPos);
        float Cof =  1-Point/HeightOcean+0.4; 
        if(Cof>1) Cof = 1;
        
        float DisVF = distance(viewPos,FragPos);
         Cof = Cof * (DisVF/50);
         if(Cof>1)Cof = 1;
        
        
        
        
        result = mix(result, ColorOcean , Cof  );
    }
}





//if(OceanCam)
//result = mix(result,ColorOcean,  0.5 );

  
  //if(distance(viewPos,FragPos)>50)
      
  if(Fog.enable) 
  {
    result = mix(result,Fog.fogColor,  DisF  ); 
  }  
  
  
    
    
if(texture(material.diffuse, texCoords).a < 0.4)
        discard;
    
    
    if(OceanMesh)
    FragColor = vec4(result,  0.7);
    else
   FragColor = vec4(result, texture(material.diffuse, texCoords)[3]);

    
    //FragColor = texture(material.diffuse, texCoords);
}

// 00000 calculates the color when using a directional light.
vec3 CalcDirLight(DirLight light, vec3 normal, vec3 viewDir)
{
   vec3 lightDir = normalize(-light.direction);
   
  
   
   float diff = 1;
  diff   = max(dot(normal, lightDir), 0.0);
    
   
    vec3 reflectDir = reflect(-lightDir, normal);  
    float spec = pow(max(dot(viewDir, reflectDir), 0.0), material.shininess);
    vec3 specular = light.specular * spec * texture(material.specular, texCoords).rgb;  
    

    vec3 diffuse = light.diffuse * vec3(texture(material.diffuse, texCoords)) * diff;
    //vec3 specular = light.specular  * vec3(texture(material.specular, texCoords));
    return diffuse + specular + light.ambient * vec3(texture(material.diffuse, texCoords))  ;
}

// calculates the color when using a point light.
vec3 CalcPointLight(PointLight light, vec3 normal, vec3 fragPos, vec3 viewDir)
{
    vec3 lightDir = normalize(light.position - fragPos);
    // diffuse shading
    float diff = max(dot(normal, lightDir), 0.0);
    // specular shading
    vec3 reflectDir = reflect(-lightDir, normal);
    float spec = pow(max(dot(viewDir, reflectDir), 0.0), material.shininess);
    // attenuation
    float distance = length(light.position - fragPos);
    float attenuation = 1.0 / (light.constant + light.linear * distance + light.quadratic * (distance * distance));    
    // combine results
  //  vec3 ambient = light.ambient * vec3(texture(material.diffuse, texCoords));
    vec3 diffuse = light.diffuse * diff * vec3(texture(material.diffuse, texCoords));
    vec3 specular = light.specular * spec * vec3(texture(material.specular, texCoords));
    
    diffuse *= attenuation;
    specular *= attenuation;
    return (diffuse + specular);
}

// calculates the color when using a spot light.
vec3 CalcSpotLight(SpotLight light, vec3 normal, vec3 fragPos, vec3 viewDir)
{
    vec3 lightDir = normalize(light.position - fragPos);
    // diffuse shading
    float diff = max(dot(normal, lightDir), 0.0);
    // specular shading
    vec3 reflectDir = reflect(-lightDir, normal);
    float spec = pow(max(dot(viewDir, reflectDir), 0.0), material.shininess);
    // attenuation
    float distance = length(light.position - fragPos);
    float attenuation = 1.0 / (light.constant + light.linear * distance + light.quadratic * (distance * distance));    
    // spotlight intensity
    float theta = dot(lightDir, normalize(-light.direction)); 
    float epsilon = light.cutOff - light.outerCutOff;
    float intensity = clamp((theta - light.outerCutOff) / epsilon, 0.0, 1.0);
    // combine results
    vec3 ambient = light.ambient * vec3(texture(material.diffuse, texCoords));
    vec3 diffuse = light.diffuse * diff * vec3(texture(material.diffuse, texCoords));
    vec3 specular = light.specular * spec * vec3(texture(material.specular, texCoords));
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    ambient *= attenuation * intensity;
    diffuse *= attenuation * intensity;
    specular *= attenuation * intensity;
    return (ambient + diffuse + specular);
}
```

**Так вот три вопроса**

---

1. **В чем причина такой ужасной просадки**
2. **Можно ли как то не в ручном
   режиме переотправлять данные, как стандартный геометричиский шейдер
   не зная имен переменных как то это делает.**
3. **Ну и где можно
   посмотреть код стандартного шейдера который дефолтный пока я свой не
   привязываю.**